# Is it possible to hover a button and show an image?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Hope you're all fine.
What I'm trying to do is when I over button, there'll be an image which will be displayed from this button.

Here is the code :

```js
$('a[rel=popover]').popover({
  html: true,
  trigger: 'hover',
  placement: 'bottom',
  content: function(){return '<img src="'+$(this).data('img') + '" />';}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" >
    <a class="btn" rel="popover" data-img="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/logo/mdb192x192.jpg"> ABC TEST </a>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Cordially

Comment: You can place image element below your button with style property of `display: none`. On hover, just make a function that gets the image by ID and changes the style property to `display: block`

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. I'm not really good with JS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work perfectly fine, you can adjust the positioning of the image by changing style property.

```js
$('#myBtn').hover(function(){
  $("#myImage").css("display", "block")
}, function(){
    $("#myImage").css("display", "none")});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" >
    <div class="btn" id="myBtn" > ABC TEST </div>
    <img style="display:none;" id="myImage"       src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/logo/mdb192x192.jpg"></img>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Working perfectly. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.my-button').hover(
   function() {
    $('.my-img').show();
   }, 
   function() {
    $('.my-img').hide();
   }
  )
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" >
<a class="btn my-button" rel="popover" data-img="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/logo/mdb192x192.jpg"> ABC TEST </a>
</div>
<img class="my-img" style='display:none;' src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/logo/mdb192x192.jpg" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
 </html>
```